# Запустить openvpn через коммандную строку в режиме клиента

Tags: windows, vpn, openvpn

Как мне запустить opevpn.exe в режиме клиента через коммандную строку, подключиться к openvpn серверу и потом, через некоторое время отключиться тоже через компактную строку? Разумеется, мне не нужно, чтобы окно openvpn было видно. Это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Данный код запускает клиент openvpn и завершает процесс через 30 секунд после запуска openvpn. Подключение в соответствии с конфигом в файле `c:\client.ovpn`

```
start /b cmd /c "c:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe" c:\client.ovpn
timeout 30
taskkill /f /im:openvpn.exe
```

Сохранить как файл .cmd, например **openvpn.cmd**
Для скрытого выполнения команд можно использовать утилиты **hidec** или **hidcon**.

Например `hidec c:\openvpn.cmd`

Запускать надо с правами пользователя, достаточными для установления openvpn соединения.

Comment: а разве можно через cmd в винде залогинится атоматичести в vpn? Если в конфиге прописать user имя то при выполнении подключения Tue Aug 11 13:39:39 2020 NOTE: --user option is not implemented on Windows